# Sqoop import: Specify `select` expressions in a separate file?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

When importing data from MySQL to Hive I need to normalize several text fields containing phone numbers. This requires quite complex logic which is hard to express in Sqoop command line with a single SQL `replace` function.
Is it possible to specify SQL `select` expressions in a separate file and refer to it from a command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$ sqoop --options-file /users/homer/work/option.txt -
```

your option.txt will look as:

```
# Options file for Sqoop import
#

# Specifies the tool being invoked
import

# Connect parameter and value
--connect
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db

# Username parameter and value
--username
foo

## Query
--query
"select * from Table WHERE \$CONDITIONS"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query option in your sqoop as:

```
sqoop import --username $username\
--password $pwd\
--connect jdbc:mysql://54.254.177.160:3306/msta_casestudy\
--query "SELECT a1,  b1,c1 FROM MyTable WHERE \$CONDITIONS"\
--split-by HMS_PACK_ID\
--target-dir /home/root/myfile\
--fields-terminated-by "|" -m 1
```

If your query is spanned across multiple lines you either you can pass a file with `--options-file` or, in your command prompt or shell script you can code query as below (please note "\" specifies line concatenations)

```
--query
select \
col1 \
,col2 \
,col3 \
,col4       \
from table1 a \
join \
table2 b \
etc etc
```

Comment: Command line `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://server/db --username xxxx --password yyyy  --options-file sql.txt --target-dir /data/test -m 1  --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table phone
` where sql.txt contains  `--query select mobile, name from test` does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: Please try adding WHERE \$CONDITIONS after your table name.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried putting different argument combinations in `optios-file`, all result in general error message from Sqoop. It would help if you could post an example of using `options-file` to pass `select` expression that works for you.

Comment: You can create sqoop as: